# passing input values to javascript under laravel

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, input

I have an HTML form with input fields. I am trying to get the data from the input fields to be passed to a javascript function for processing. I am trying to get the value of "tenantid" but the only thing I get, when displaying the value in the popup:

> first objectHMTLFormElement

How can I get values entered in the form to the Javascript code?

TIA

I have:
**testing.blade.php**

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/test.js') }}">
    </script>

    [.. snip ..]

    <form id="oogie" class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('') }}/dashboard">      
                {{ csrf_field() }}


            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('tenantid') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                    <label for="tenantid" class="col-md-4 control-label"> Tenant ID </label>

                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input id="tenantid" type="integer" class="form-control" name="tenantid" value="{{ old('tenantid') }}" required autofocus>

                        @if ($errors->has('tenantid'))
                            <span class="help-block">
                                <strong>{{ $errors->first('tenantid') }}</strong>
                            </span>
                        @endif
                    </div>
                </div>
      </form>

      [... snip ...]

      <button class="ClickMe" onclick="testme();">Click me</button>
```

**test.js**

```
function testme()
{
alert("got in");
var parameters = document.getElementById("oogie");

alert("first " + parameters );

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your script isn't trying to access the value of the field, but the field itself.

You should use `document.getElementById(ID).value`. This will fix your issue.

Comment: Thanks - that was it.